# JohnDoe wants someone to pull from johndoe:master:

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have no much experience with git or github and today I got a mail requesting someone (me) to pull the master branch.

Could someone lead me on the steps I should take to do this?
I always work with individual projects so I have never merged of pulled something

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Help.GitHub: Sending pull requests](http://help.github.com/pull-requests/) gives the following procedure for merging in a pull request:

> ### Merging a Pull Request
>
> Once the pull request is deemed
>   satisfactory, someone with push access
>   to the destination repository must
>   apply the changes and push the updated
>   branch. There are a variety of ways to
>   accomplish this. Two popular methods
>   are described below.
>
> #### Fetch and Merge
>
> This is the most common method of fetching and applying
>   changes. It requires adding a remote
>   for the person that sent the pull
>   request, fetching from that
>   repository, merging the requested
>   branch, fixing any conflicts, and
>   pushing the newly merged branch back
>   to the repository:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout master
> $ git remote add kneath git://github.com/kneath/jobs.git
> $ git fetch kneath
> $ git merge kneath/error-page
> $ git push origin master
> ```
>
> #### Patch and Apply
>
> The fetch and merge approach works great when you’re
>   working on a team or repeatedly
>   applying changes from the same small
>   group of people. Another approach
>   that’s a bit quicker in one-off cases
>   is to use `git-am`.
>
> Every pull request has a .patch URL
>   where you can grab a textual patch
>   file to feed into the `git-am` command:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout master
> $ curl http://github.com/github/jobs/pull/25.patch | git am
> $ git push origin master
> ```

For further detail, check the linked pages below.

#### See also:

- [Help.GitHub: Sending pull requests](http://help.github.com/pull-requests/)
- [I Have a Pull Request on GitHub, Now What?](http://www.viget.com/extend/i-have-a-pull-request-on-github-now-what/)
- [How to Handle a Pull Request from GitHub](http://markosullivan.ca/how-to-handle-a-pull-request-from-github/)
- [git-pulls: Manage GitHub pull requests from the command line](http://thechangelog.com/post/2878756980/git-pulls-command-line-tool-for-github-pull-requests)